# Laravel Authentication don´t work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a login with laravel however, when I use Auth :: Attempt ........ always return false. I have reviewed the code several times, but still can not find the error. could guide me please ?? thanks :)

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class Users extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

}
```

controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Users as user;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function PreLogin(Request $request){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'EmailLogin' => 'require|email',
            'PasswordLogin' => 'require|min:6'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){

            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'error' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
            ]);
        }else{

            return $this->Login($request);
        }

    }

    private function Login(Request $request){

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->EmailLogin, 'password' => $request->PasswordLogin])){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'error' => 'not login'
            ]);

        }

    }
}
```

auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Users::class,
        ],

//         'users' => [
//             'driver' => 'database',
//             'table' => 'users',
//         ],
    ],
```

Comment: is the user's password hashed in the db?

Comment: You can post your error log.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: How do you create the user?

Answer (score 0):

use **auth** middleware on your route on which you are using Auth :: Attempt